# Traveling to Japan from Poland on American passport

Tags: usa, japan, poland

I am a US citizen with a valid American passport, currently living in Poland (I'm Polish American). I am thinking about traveling to Japan for a couple of weeks and then returning back to Poland. Do you know if I can use my American passport for that?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you expand on your problem a little bit? Why wouldn't using your US passport be okay?

Comment: How did you enter Poland in the first place?

Comment: @phoog - I live in Poland since when I was 4.
@JonathanReez - `Why wouldn't using your US passport be okay?` - this is exactly what I want to know, because I'm not sure.

Comment: And you haven't left Poland since you were 4? Or you've only traveled in the EU?

Answer (score 3):

US citizens get visa free entry into Japan for short stays like you are planning.

Comment: Do you know if there could be any problems with me retuning back to Poland on American passport?

Comment: That I suppose would depend on your current status in Poland.  Do you have a residence permit or are you flying under the radar or dual citizenship?

Comment: I have dual citizenship, Polish and American. Basically I could apply for a Polish passport, but since my American passport is valid, then I don't know if there's a need for that.

Comment: Not sure of Poland's rules, but most countries require you to enter and exit on their passport if you are a citizen.  If you have both passports, then use the US one for Japan and the Polish one for entering & exiting Poland.  If you only have a US passport, then perhaps someone can chime in on Poland's exact rules on the matter.

Comment: Okay, then I better apply for a Polish passport. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Getting the passport is a good idea, especially with the current threats of forcing visa rules on Americans to visit the EU.

Comment: "Most countries" have no requirement for their citizens to use that country's passport; the US is the outlier in that regard. @AdrianWydmanski: if, however, you try to enter Poland with your US passport, without proof of Polish citizenship, you risk being denied entry as an overstayer. If you have a Polish national ID card, however, you will be fine unless Poland has and enforces a requirement to use a Polish passport for travel outside the EU. (Even the US does not *enforce* its legal requirement for its citizens to use a US passport.)

Comment: @phoog - The countries I am familiar with do, but that is neither here nor there (other than your excuse for nitpicking).  It is ALWAYS the best idea to enter and exit a country using that country's passport when you are a citizen of that country.

Comment: @Tom that of course is true. The countries I'm familiar with are mostly European, plus Canada and the US. I do not know whether Poland has such a law, but I presume the OP has *some* evidence of his Polish nationality given that he lives in Poland. Obviously the simplest, most practical, and most certain solution is to get a Polish passport.